# Video Asset URLs not rendering

Tags: craft3, assets, video

I'm trying to output the video files from within a block but get a `Calling unknown method: craft\elements\db\AssetQuery::url()` error when using the following:

```
{{ block.video.videoFileWebm.url }}
```

Assets in this volume have public URLs so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

**FULL CODE**

```
{% if block.video %}

                <video {% if block.video.videoAutoplay %}autoplay{% endif %} {% if block.video.videoLoop %}loop{% endif %} 
                                                    
                    {% if block.video.videoThumbnail %}
                    {% set optimizedImages = block.video.videoThumbnail.one().imageVariants16by9 %}
                    poster="{{ optimizedImages.srcset() }}"
                    {% endif %} muted>

                    {% if block.video.videoFileWebm %}
                        <source src="{{ block.video.videoFileWebm.url }}" type="video/webm">
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if block.video.videoFileOgg %}
                        <source src="{{ block.video.videoFileOgg.url }}" type="video/ogg">
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if block.video.videoFileMp4 %}
                        <source src="{{ block.video.videoFileMp4.url }}" type="video/mp4">
                    {% endif %}
                    
                    <p>This browser does not support the video element.</p>
                </video>

            {% endif %}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, is "video" a block type in a matrix, or is it a matrix field in an entry? I'm confused because you're doing `block.video` when it looks like you mean `entry.videoBlocks`, more specifically `entry.videoBlocks.one()`?

Comment: ...Or is "video" an entries select field in a matrix block? Either way you need to add some eager loading. Check your deprecation errors in Utilities and you'll see what needs fixing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asset fields return like an array so they can potentially have more than one item, you need to request the first item only with `.one()` (as opposed to requesting `.all()`)

```
//First check if the asset field has more than zero items
{% if block.video.videoFileWebm|length %}
    // Retrieve the first and only item in the asset field
    <source src="{{ block.video.videoFileWebm.one().url }}" type="video/webm">
{% endif %}
```

I would also set `block.video` to a variable to clean up the code a bit and maybe speed it up a little.

Comment: It's not really accurate to say that "asset fields presume that you may have more than one item", it's more the case that element queries need to be _executed_ - whether that's `.one()` or `.all()` or `.ids()` or any of the other execution methods.

Comment: @JamesSmith you're right, that was badly written, updated!

Comment: Sorry for splitting hairs, but still not quite right - Calling an asset field without one of the execution methods will not return an array - it'll return an _element query object_: that query then needs to be executed before you can access the result - which in this case would be an Asset object.

Comment: Hey, I'm happy with it – it's easy to understand for all levels, but feel free to edit if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't executed your element queries. You'll need to call `.one()` on each related element, or, better, use eager loading to do the whole lot in one go:

I've assumed in the example below that 'video' is an entry select field type inside a matrix block type called 'video' inside a matrix field called 'matrixBlocks':

```
{% set matrixBlocks = entry.matrixBlocks.with([    
    'video:video.videoThumbnail',
    'video:video.videoFileWebm',
    'video:video.videoFileOgg',
    'video:video.videoFileMp4',
]).all() %}

{% for block in matrixBlocks %}
    {% if block.type == 'video' and block.video|length %}
        {% set videoEntry = block.video[0] %}
        <video {{ videoEntry.videoAutoplay ? 'autoplay' }} {{ videoEntry.videoLoop ? 'loop'}}
            {% if videoEntry.videoThumbnail %}
                {% set optimizedImages = videoEntry.videoThumbnail[0].imageVariants16by9 %}
                poster="{{ optimizedImages.srcset() }}"
            {% endif %} muted>

            {% if videoEntry.videoFileWebm %}
                <source src="{{ videoEntry.videoFileWebm[0].url }}" type="video/webm">
            {% endif %}
            {% if videoEntry.videoFileOgg %}
                <source src="{{ videoEntry.videoFileOgg[0].url }}" type="video/ogg">
            {% endif %}
            {% if videoEntry.videoFileMp4 %}
                <source src="{{ videoEntry.videoFileMp4[0].url }}" type="video/mp4">
            {% endif %}
            
            <p>This browser does not support the video element.</p>
        </video>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```